# Driver mysql não é encontrado quando a aplicação é rodada a partir de um jar

Tags: java, sql, driver

Desenvolvi um sistema de cadastro de funcionários. Nesse sistema a persistência dos dados é feita num banco mysql. Quando executo o programa pelo pacote o sistema funciona normalmente, porém quando gerei um jar executável ele não acha o driver do mysql.

O Driver do mysql está no caminho abaixo:

```
c:\jars\jdbc_mysql.jar
```

A classe principal da aplicação está no pacote abaixo:

```
br\com\vl1\principal\SistemaCadastro.java
```

Executando da forma abaixo o sistema funciona:

```
c:\raiz\java -cp c:\jars\jdbc_mysql.jar;. br.com.vl1.principal.SistemaCadastro
```

Porém quando executo da forma abaixo ele não acha o Driver Mysql

```
c:\raiz\java -cp c:\jars\jdbc_mysql.jar;. -jar SistemaCadastro.jar
```

O jar foi gerado com o comando seguinte:

```
 jar -cvfm SistemaCadastro.jar META-INF\MANIFEST.MF br
```

Abaixo segue a exception gerada quando tento salvar um registro no banco:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sistema_cadastro
```

Todo o processo foi executado pelo prompt de comando. Não estou usando IDE e gostaria de uma solução por linha de comando.

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você compilou o jar do driver do mysql junto? Se não, provavelmente a causa é esta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solução "na unha" seria incluir o seu jar e o jar do driver do MySQL no *Classpath* e então rodar a classe `main`:

```
java -cp c:\jars\jdbc_mysql.jar;c:\raiz\java\SistemaCadastro.jar  br.com.vl1.principal.SistemaCadastro
```

É claro que essa solução é mais para desenvolvimento. Para a conveniência do usuário final é possível configurar um ponto de entrada e o *Classpath* no `MANIFEST.MF`.

Digamos que você distribua sua aplicação da seguinte maneira:

```
raiz/
    lib/
        jdbc_mysql.jar
    SistemaCadastro.jar
        META-INF/
            MANIFEST.MF
        br.com.vl1.principal.SistemaCadastro
```

Onde o conteúdo de `MANIFEST.MF` é:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Vlamir78
Main-Class: br.com.vl1.principal.SistemaCadastro
Class-Path: lib/jdbc_mysql.jar
```

Nesse caso o comando abaixo seria suficiente para rodar sua aplicação:

```
java -jar SistemaCadastro.jar
```

**Update**: Uma terceira forma é criar um *[Uber Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar)* que reempacota todas as dependências junto com sua aplicação. Dito isso, esse é um assunto mais avançado que exige cautela; existem algumas questões legais e técnicas a serem consideradas quando pretendemos fazer isso. Se for por esse caminho vale a pena dar uma olhada em ferramentas como o [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html).

---

#### FONTES:

- [SOen: include external jar when running java -jar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2910115/664577)
- [SOen: Execute jar file with multiple classpath libraries from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13018100/664577)
- [The Java™ Tutorials - Lesson: Packaging Programs in JAR Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html)