# Ficheiro .jar consola de comandos - programa cliente servidor

Tags: java, eclipse

Desenvolvi um programa do género cliente servidor, em que possuo dois mains:

- um para correr o servidor
- outro para correr varios clientes

Para extrair o ficheiro .jar do ecplise faço export runnable Jar File.

Consigo correr na consola de comandos quando tenho só um main mas e com dois mains? É que quando faço o export tenho de clarificar o main para correr o programa.

Não faz sentido juntar os dois mains uma vez que só necessito de correr o servidor uma vez. Preciso sim é de correr o cliente várias vezes

Comment: Não seria o caso de apenas executar cada jar em um janela do CMD diferente?

Comment: Olá rrr, nao sei se entendi direito a sua necessidade, porém me parece que você tem duas classes *main*, uma para o cliente e outra para o servidor dentro do mesmo jar correto? Seu problema é que você quer selecionar qual das classes rodar, é isso? Se sim você pode fazer isso colocando o jar da aplicação no classpath e especificando a classe a ser executada. Veja [o primeiro comando desta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/167772/100).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly obrigado pelo interesse. Já sei como solucionar o problema vou postar a resposta dê uma vista de olhos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente quando existe um programa do género cliente-servidor a solução na criação de um runnable jar com dois mains é separar e criar dois jar's à parte. Um jar com o servidor, e outro jar com o cliente. Deste modo é possível lançar o servidor e vários clientes ligados a esse servidor porque eles ligam se pela mesma server socket.

Comment: Essa é a melhor solução no longo prazo, até porque em boa parte dos casos o código todo não  é reaproveitável entre cliente e servidor, não vale a pena "distribuir" um jar com o código do servidor para um cliente e vice-versa. Do ponto de vista de evolução é melhor ter módulos separados. Dito isso, para um projeto simples não há nada de errado em usar algo como o [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) para gerar dois jars executáveis com MANIFESTs difetentes para o mesmo módulo.

Comment: sim exatamente assim até ficam divididos os programas